Installed the package pgfornament but doesn't recognize colors
I installed the package: pgfornament
But whenever I try a color, different from the very basics, I get a very long error prompt, in one of the lines it says:
! Package xcolor Error: Undefined color `SpringGreen'
Any ideas?

Please provide a full but minimal example, so we know what exactly you are doing. I would not expect a colorname like SpringGreen to work out of the box. xcolor need to be loaded with options to support that name. But you show no details....

In the xcolor"s documentation (texdoc xcolor on the terminal) or on the ctan https://mirror.funkfreundelandshut.de/latex/macros/latex/contrib/xcolor/xcolor.pdf, hte springgreen is obtained with the option dvipsnames
